# Setup Swagger with Jaxrs eclipse and tomcat

Tags: jax-rs, swagger

I m new to Swagger project. I used the swagger editor to create an API and then generated server code for JAX-RS. What I need is to integrate the code with an eclipse project and deploy it on Tomcat. 
However, I see that the swagger generated code uses a jetty server. Is there any example showing how to set up swagger with eclipse and Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the code generator is a war file.  You can run that anywhere, including with tomcat.  If you want an example of doing so, please look here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/master/java/java-jaxrs-cxf/pom.xml

But it is truly just a war file, so it's portable across Java servlet containers.

Comment: thnx,I ll have a look